# NavigationLinkError (from YT Video)

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I Was following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GiCTgsH0dtk) and got this error anyone know a work around others in the comments having trouble with the same thing so i thought id help

Do you know the correct way to handle this new error for this piece of code?

```
NavigationLink(destination: SignUp(show: self.$show), isActive: self.$show) {
                            
                            Text("")
                        }
                        .hidden()
                        
                        Login(show: self.$show)
                    }
```

Error:

> 'init(destination:isActive:label:)' was deprecated in iOS 16.0: use NavigationLink(value:label:) inside a NavigationStack or NavigationSplitView

Comment: That isn’t an error it is a warning. Look into navigation destination with isPresented

Answer (score 0):

First, change your `NavigationLink` to `NavigationStack`.
And lastly, where your - if you have one - `.navigationTitle("")` goes (this is where `NavigationView` closes), Xcode is asking you to add a `.navigationDestination()` as following:

```
.navigationDestination(isPresented: $show) {
                        //Whatever View you want to display...
}
```

This alert, not error, happens because of iOS 16 and Apple's constant changes on the Swift and Swift's frameworks changes.